# Узнать раскладку клавиатуры (и записать в текстовый файл)

Tags: c#

Я уже довольно долго бьюсь над вопросом того, как можно узнать раскладку (точнее язык (то есть ru и en)), а после записать в файл (вообще, я считываю клавиши с клавиатуры, и если раскладка русская, то в файл записывается ru, в противном en). Я написал код, но он работает только наполовину: при запуске в .txt файл записывается раскладка, которая была при запуске программы, но когда я её меняю, он продолжает записывать в файл ту же самую раскладку что раньше. И я пытаюсь понять в чём проблема (может в StreamWriter или чём-то другом). В общем, очень нужна помощь. (Если нужно, могу весь код кинуть)
Вот сама часть того кода:

```
        {
            string layoutType = InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage.Culture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName;
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(Path.GetTempPath() + @"\keyLog.txt", true);
            sw.Write(Convert.ToString(layoutType));
            sw.Close();
            return layoutType;
        }
```

Comment: Подсказка: запись в файл можно сделать так `File.AppendAllText(Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), "keyLog.txt"), layoutType)`

Comment: Так вы можете считывать не сканкоды клавиш а их символы и не мучаться с этой проблемой? Хук у вас наверняка уже стоит, осталось разобраться, как получать символы, а не скан-коды. А чтобы ловить сам факт смены раскладки пользователем, нужно добавлять обработчик `WndProc` и ловить сообщение `WM_INPUTLANGCHANGE` из Message Loop. Но вообще обсуждать потенциально вредоносные приложения на StackOverflow не принято. Хотя, в Winforms [есть вот такое событие](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.inputlanguagechanging?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-5.0)

Comment: @aepot, возможно его можно использовать как потенциально вредоносное, но оно мне нужно лично для своего пк, так что вот

Comment: Вы правда не указали в тегах, что за тип приложения, но я догадался, что это формы. Ну я вам выше описал, куда копать, создайте обработчик события `InputLanguageChanging`, там и ловите факт смены раскладки, по ссылке есть детальный пример.

Comment: @aepot, честно скажу, что это консоль (в следующий раз буду указывать). Я вроде читал где-то что у консольных приложений есть с этим проблема, так что не факт, что это вообще исправимо. Можно будет подумать про переход программы на Forms (где-то завтра прикреплю весь код вероятно)

Comment: Без Message Loop вам не получить событие, вы обращаетесь к формам (`InputLanguage` оттуда), значит вам ничего не стоит создать экземпляр Application и запустить.

Comment: если для личного пользования то тогда проще поставить себе на компьютор PuntoSwitcher и включить функцию дневника. Если хочется самому написать - проще не извращатся и поикать уже имеющийся ответы на стек оверфлоу по слову "кейлоггер". Более того, есть даже готовые решения на гитхабе.